# Can we use batch normalization with transfer learning for an instance with different data distribution?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, convolution, batch-normalization

This [tutorial](https://r2rt.com/implementing-batch-normalization-in-tensorflow.html) has the tensor-flow implementation of batch normal layer for training and testing phases.

**When we using transfer learning is it ok to use batch normalization layer? Specially when data distributions are different.**

Because in the inference phase BN layer just uses fixed mini batch mean and variance(Which is calculated with the help of training distribution).
So if our model has a different distribution of data , *can it give wrong results?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With transfer learning, you're transferring the learned parameters from a domain to another.
Usually, this means that you're keeping fixed the learned values of the convolutional layer whilst adding new fully connected layers that learn to classify the features extracted by the CNN.

When you add batch normalization to every layer, you're injecting values sampled from the input distribution into the layer, in order to force the output layer to be normally distributed.
In order of doing that, you compute the exponential moving average of the layer output and then in the testing phase, you subtract this value from the layer output.

Although data dependent, this mean values (for every convolutional layer) are computed on the **output** of the layer, thus on the transformation learned.

Thus, in my opinion, the various averages that the BN layer subtracts from its convolutional layer output are general enough to be transferred: they are computed on the *transformed* data and not on the original data.
Moreover, the convolutional layer learns to extract local patterns thus they're more robust and difficult to influence.

Thus, **in short** and in my opinion:

you can apply transfer learning of convolutional layer with batch norm applied. But on fully connected layers the influence of the computed value (that see the whole input and not only local patches) can bee too much data dependent and thus I'll avoid it.

However, as a rule of thumb: if you're insecure about something just try it and see if it works!

Comment: So you are saying BN layers between FC layers should be re trained and we can use BN layers between convolutional layers as it is.  Am I correct ?

Comment: In my opinion, this sounds reasonable. However just try both and see what happen. I'd like to know the results of your tests next!

Comment: If I freeze the batch norm layers, does it mean that I also freeze the convolutional layers? For example, in the prototxt file of VGG19 in Caffe, the `lr_mult` values are set to `0` in the `conv1_1/bn` layer, but not in `conv1_1` layer. Does it mean that the `conv1_1` layer does learn? Or does the `conv1_1/bn` layer zero the gradient?